# Kafka retention hours and how to validate Kafka keep the data for the specific period

Tags: apache-kafka

We can set retention period by the following Kafka cli

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper hostname:2181 --alter --config retention.ms=172800000 --topic <topic_name>
```

and we can verified that setting is set correctly by the following cli

```
kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --describe --topics-with-overrides
```

in fact the retention hours will keep the data for each partition and thats ok

but is it possible also to verify data on each partition that not reached the retention threshold ?

for example

lets say we have topic with 10 partition , and we set retention hours for 2 day
and from Kafka side , Kafka should keep the data no more then 2 day

can we validate data on topics are not reached the 2 days?

One option is to access each partition topic and use the Linux command `ls -ltr` , and verify time stamp  , and verify files are not stay more then 2 days , but we want to know maybe other options for this verification